# MVC 4 - AntiForgeryValidationToken only creating cookie for first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

Okay, this is an odd case we were working on yesterday. When our site is loaded up, the first request for this form works as expected. Anti forgery validation goes through, nothing errors out, everything is fine. However, after the first initially successful use, additional browser requests stop generating the cookie portion of the anti forgery token. All further attempts to post will return a 500 indicating the cookie isn't present. Looking in browser resources confirms the cookie isn't present. I'm assuming that it's some manner of configuration issue, as things work fine in our testing and development environments, but the issue comes up once we move to our staging environment and I'm running out of ideas.

I have a controller action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public bool someFunction(string someParameter) {
    // Do things
    return success;
}
```

On our page, I have a from setup like this

```
<form id="someForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="text" name="someField" />
</form>
```

And it's wired up like this:

```
$("#someForm").On("submit", function(e) {
e.PreventDefault();
var url = "path/to/action";
var someFieldVal = $(this).Find('[name="someField"]').val();
var token = $(this).Find('[name="__RequestValidationToken"]');
var data = { '__RequestVerificationToken': token, 'someParameter': someFieldval };
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: function (response) {//do stuff}
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ajax posts you put the token in the header not the data.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {//do stuff}
|;
```

EDIT

I forgot about the other half to this.

You say the second browser post doesn't have a anti-forgery cookie.  That would be a problem if that is happening.  However, from your code example, it seems your ajax post is not including the cookie not a browser request.

The cookie is an HtttpOnly cookie.  Which means (amoung other things) that javascript doesn't have access to it.  If you were using ajax to post a form it would include the cookie.  However, your posting data.  So it's not including the anti-forgery cookie because ajax is not allowed to read the cookie and include the cookie in the post.

Some people will put a form on each page that's used just for ajax posts.  However, I prefer posting data over forms.  So the second half to what I posted is to create an authorization attribute.  This attribute looks for the token in the header and then validates it.

Here's the class that creates the authorize attribute that I use.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null
                    ? antiForgeryCookie.Value
                    : null;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just add the attribute to each controller you want anti-forgery token validated.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts]
public class SomeController : Controller
{   }
```

I think this is that site where I first learned how to do this: http://richiban.uk/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/

Comment: Okay, fair enough point, I'll adjust my code to do so from here out, but would this cause the behavior of the Cookie portion of the validation token only being served to the first browser that requests the page?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the other half to this.  I updated my answer to include all the details.